# Creating a dependent spinner in android studio? select a type of pet and then a breed depending on the type of pet e.g. dog and then the breed

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, spinner, android-spinner

https://github.com/tmo171/Vetserviceactual2.git

the issue is position in petsignup java class. i want the user to select a type of pet and then a breed depending on the type of pet e.g. dog and then beagle.